# How to use google-oauth-java-client?

Tags: java, google-oauth

I want to use **google-oauth-java-client** to get authorization code from [Sina Weibo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sina_Weibo).

This is the GET method that get code from Sina

```
https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=70090552&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1/weibo
```

Please solve this without web page, **only client**!

Can anybody give me some advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get method use browser and return the code
Post method use `HttpRequest` and we can get parameter from `HtppResponse`

So if you want to get code, just use browser and redirect to the url to get code

Here is how I get `access_token`

If you want, you can use google-oauth-java-client to authorization twitter facebook

I solve this by javadoc which show me some examples. [This](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.32.1/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/package-summary.html#package.description) is the root of JavaDoc and [this](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.32.1/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/TokenRequest.html) is the package I use to solve

Here is the example I write

```
//   https://server.example.com/token server url example
try {
  TokenResponse response =
      new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
          new GenericUrl("here is the server url "), "here write your code")
          .setRedirectUri("here write the redirectUrl")
          .set("client_id","here write your client_id")
          .set("client_secret","here write your client_secret")
          .set("Other else need","Other else need")
          .execute();
  System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
} catch (TokenResponseException e) {
  if (e.getDetails() != null) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
    if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
      System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
    }
    if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
      System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
    }
  } else {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that google oauth client is only suitable for google services, which has clientid and client secret both in POST BODY. However, other oauth servers usually have these in POST Header Authorization field after Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/dailymotion-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/DailyMotionSample.java?repo=samples) you can get find the solution.

http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/dailymotion-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/DailyMotionSample.java?repo=samples

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10) will help you. First understand the mechanism and implement it according to your scenario.

Comment: Looks more like a comment than an answer.